# Zsh prompt produces an error

Tags: command-line, unix, git, zsh, oh-my-zsh

I have the default prompt for oh-my-zsh, which is great when I have a git repo, but if there is no git repo its actually failing instead of putting nothing.  I trapped an ascii image to err just for humors sake, and then when I cd out of a git repo it has the path + ascii-image as the prompt!  This is very annoying and I imagine there must be a way to write the prompt so that it isn't erring out?

Prompt:

```
${ret_status}%{$fg_bold[green]%}%p %{$fg[cyan]%}%c %{$fg_bold[blue]%}$(git_prompt_info)%{$fg_bold[blue]%} % %{$reset_color%}
```

Comment: You should give your current prompt setting here, otherwise it'll be hard to get any clue what is going on...

Comment: @mpy I added the prompt - I have no idea why I didn't include it originally XD